# Constructing a 3D pyramid with CSS but just need the final touch

Tags: css

I'm almost there, I found the perfect CSS pyramid: https://codepen.io/SL20XX/pen/NZLGjx

But I want to apply this gradient instead of the single "#00B4FF" color:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(39deg, #12103E 0%, #721B34 100%);
```

I tried many tweaks but doesn't work. I'm confused with the "$color" variable.

How would you do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: They seem to be drawing the triangles with borders and then setting the border color - this has to be a color, a linear-gradient is not a color in that sense, it is a quasi image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a border-image on each surface rather than a border color.

This snippet does this but has to clip each surface back into a triangle shape.

Note: to get the shading effect you need to decide what linear-gradient you want for each of the lighten/darken colors in your original and subsitute those for the one linear-gradient used here.

```html
<style>
  .container {
    --color: #00B4FF;
    --speed: 5s;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 300px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 40%;
  }
  
  .side {
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 150px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 120px solid #ccc;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    animation: spin var(--speed) infinite linear;
  }
  
  .back {
    animation-delay: calc(var(--speed) / -2);
  }
  
  .right {
    animation-delay: calc(var(--speed) / -4);
  }
  
  .left {
    animation-delay: calc(var(--speed) * -0.75);
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(30deg);
      /*border-bottom-color: lighten(#0000FF, 5%);*/
      border-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
    }
    25% {
      transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg);
      /*border-bottom-color: darken(#0000FF, 5%);*/
      border-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    25.1% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(30deg);
      /*border-bottom-color: darken(#0000FF, 12%);*/
      border-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
    }
    74.9% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
      transform: rotateY(270deg) rotateX(30deg);
      /*border-bottom-color: darken(#0000FF, 15%);*/
      border-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(30deg);
      /*border-bottom-color: lighten(#0000FF, 5%);*/
      border-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
    }
  }
  
  .shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 175px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 40px #bbb;
    animation: shadow var(--speed) infinite linear;
  }
  
  @keyframes shadow {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="side left"></div>
  <div class="side front"></div>
  <div class="side right"></div>
  <div class="side back"></div>

  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```